# Aggregate pandas dataframe by event

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
- event,result 
- 1, 0 
- 1, 1 
- -1, 1
- -1, -1
- -1, -1
```

Now I want to aggregate to have a sum by event and result to see how many times the event is equal to one of the 3 results: (-1, 0, 1).

I already tried to use the `groupby` function, but somehow i only get half of the needed solution.

```
groupby('event').count()
```

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1** - Groupby on both columns

One approach is to add an extra column so that you can group on the two columns of interest:

```
df.assign(cnt=1).groupby(['event','result']).count()
```

This creates a new dummy column so that you can use groupby on both the `event` and `result` columns. This added column provides the `count()` method values to aggregate.

The output is:

```
              cnt
event result     
-1    -1        2
       1        1
 1     0        1
       1        1
```

**Method 2** - crosstab()

Another approach is to use the pandas [`crosstab()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#cross-tabulations) function:

```
pd.crosstab(df.event, df.result).stack()
```

This creates a cross-tabulation table for the two columns specified. The `stack()` method shifts the data so that you have one result per row.

This command returns a Series:

```
event  result
-1     -1        2
        0        0
        1        1
 1     -1        0
        0        1
        1        1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: great, the stack() is exactly what i was looking for!! @craig thanks a lot!